# How can I use Enum in switch statement

Tags: c#

What I am trying to do is detecting the type of "item" and using it inside of a switch statement and based on that, choosing correct equipment slot.
My code:

```
    public EquipmentSlot WeaponSlot;
    public EquipmentSlot ChestplateSlot;
    public EquipmentSlot LeggingsSlot;
    public EquipmentSlot HelmetSlot;

    public void EquipItem(Item item)
    {
        EquipmentSlot chosenSlot = null;
        
        switch(item.type)
        {
            case item.type.weapon:
                chosenSlot = WeaponSlot;
                break;
            case item.type.chestplate:
                chosenSlot = ChestplateSlot;
                break;
            case item.type.leggings:
                chosenSlot = LeggingsSlot;
                break;
            case item.type.helmet:
                chosenSlot = HelmetSlot;
                break;
        }

        chosenSlot.EquippedItem = item;
    }
```

Item class:

```
    public enum Type
    {
        weapon,
        chestplate,
        leggings,
        helmet
    }
    public Type type;
```

This error is showing up:
error CS0176: Member 'Item.Type.helmet' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead
(four times for each case in switch)

Comment: Don't use `Type` for your enum name it will clash with [`System.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Indeed, better use `EquipmentType` instead of just `Type`.

Comment: ... and then `case Item.EquipmentType.weapon:`. you must prefix the enum value with the name of the enum type.

Comment: If you have difficulties with syntax, let Visual Studio help you. Type **sw** then double **Tab** to create empty switch statement. Then type in your variable **item.type** in the parentheses and press enter. Your whole enum will be enumerated in the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `case item.type.weapon:` it should be `case Item.Type.weapon:`

Comment: it says that "The name 'Type' does not exist in the current context" also doesn't work with "type"

Comment: If the `Type`-enum belongs to the `Item`-class, say `case Item.Type.weapon`

Comment: but will it read information form the item parameter form EquipItem function?

Comment: `item.type` is just one value. This one value cannot contain other values. There is no such thing as `item.type.weapon`. But if you have enum `Type` defined inside class `Item` then there is such thing as `Item.Type.weapon`.

Comment: Edited the answer to be probably correct. We can't tell for sure, because the provided code has not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
switch (item.type)
    {
        case Type.weapon:
            chosenSlot = WeaponSlot;
            break;
        case Type.chestplate:
            chosenSlot = ChestplateSlot;
            break;

        .....
    }
```

but it will be much more readable if you rename Type to ArmoryType for example

Comment: i already changed it o EquipmentType